# Transparent Video (RGB+Alpha) in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, alpha-channel

I am able to export a transparent-background video in After Effects - AVI with RGB+Alpha. It was of a man talking with a green screen background.

However, once I import it to PowerPoint, a black background appears and the video is no more transparent.

Is there any way to import transparent-background video into PowerPoint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Office 2010 32-bit and the Windows 7 32-bit?

1. If yes, please refer to Echo S's reply in this thread "[Can I
   insert/link transparent avi file in PPT 2010?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/can-i-insertlink-transparent-avi-file-in-ppt-2010/eb4a2301-cd84-4203-96c3-46fc38519efe?msgId=daa16842-5885-4e84-8a92-1d6c45917ea6&tab=AllReplies&page=2)".

Sometimes, you even need K-Lite Codec instead of QuickTime.

1. If not, I am afraid your needs could not be achieved. Or you may
   create a gif as a workaround.

As for later versions of Office, PowerPoint does not support alpha channel.
I find 2 related threads in PowerPoint UserVocice forum, and you may vote up them.

- [32bit video (with alpha channel)](https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/forums/288949-powerpoint-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/16399309-32bit-video-with-alpha-channel)
- [import videos into a slideshow page while keeping the background
  transparent of the video](https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/forums/288925-powerpoint-for-mac/suggestions/39808828-import-videos-into-a-slideshow-page-while-keeping)